# CMD move all files across any subfolder, up to existing level and delete sub-folder

Tags: cmd, directory, windows-10

There are plenty of examples, but so far the only one that seems to work is this:

```
forfiles /s /m * /c "cmd /c move @file .."
```

The only problem is that it moves everything up the level I am currently at (my parent).

What I want is to run a DOS command (not batch unless I have to) on a specific folder, that will:

- find all the subfolders only (leave files in current folder alone)
- move anything in those subfolders (files and sub-sub folders)
- up to my **current level**
- delete subfolder

Thanks

Comment: you mean like this? `@FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %A IN ('DIR /B /AD-S-H "%CD%\*" ') DO @(  FOR /F "Tokens=*" %a  IN ('DIR /B /S /A-D-S-H "%CD%\%A\*') DO @( MOVE /Y "%a"   "%CD%\%~nxa" )  && RD /S /Q "%CD%\%A\" )`

Comment: when you skip the second parameter with `move`, it moves to the current folder.